# How to execute a sequence of multiple vbscripts without create an Excel instance every time?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am doing some automation work and I need to run multiple VB scripts in order to create, fill and save excel files. I have already done it successfully, but the code seems very slow to run.

My guess is, it's because every script always creates an Excel Application Object, then saves it and quits Excel like below :

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim ExcelPath
ExcelPath = WScript.Arguments(0)
'Excel File Paht is a String. First argument in Run Script Function, must be between quotes (""). Eg:"C:\test.xlsx"'
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Error: " + Err.Description)
    WScript.Quit
End If
Dim SheetName
SheetName = WScript.Arguments(1)
'Sheet Name is a String and the second argument in run script function, must to be between quotes ("").  Eg: "Sheet1"'
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Error: " + Err.Description)
    WScript.Quit
End If
Dim CellRange
CellRange = WScript.Arguments(2)
'Cell Range is a String . Third Argument in Run Script function, must to be between quotes (""). Eg: "A1:D10"'
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Error: " + Err.Description)
    WScript.Quit
End If
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelPath)
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Error: " + Err.Description)
    WScript.Quit
End If
objExcel.Application.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objSheet.Range(CellRange).Merge
objSheet.Range(CellRange).HorizontalAlignment = -4108
objWorkbook.Save
objWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = True
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Error: " + Err.Description)
    WScript.Quit
End If
```

I just want to know if there is any way to run like 25 different scripts in sequence without always create this object and save. So In my mind I would have an structure like this :

```
1. Open_excel.vbs
2. Create Sheet.vbs
3. Insert Values.vbs
4. Format Cell.vbs   
5. Save File.vbs
6. Quit Excel.vbs
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may create Excel instance once, and terminate it at the very script end, check [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56893629/2165759).